# SQLAlchemy cannot create relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model and I want to add a foreign key to it. But db.relationship is giving me an error. I am basically trying to create a model ticket that has a foreign key to `User` and another to `Event`.

Here is my code

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    """
    Simple user model
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)

    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    # mail = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    @property
    def email(self):
        """
        The email is the username in this case
        :return:
        """
        return self.username

    # This has to be hashed
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

    picture = db.Column(db.String(100),
                        server_default="/uploads/default-user-image.png",
                        nullable=False,
                        )

    # Events = db.relationship('Event', backref='empleado', lazy =True)

    # registra = db.relationship('Event', secondary='Registra')
    # boleto = db.relationship('Event', secondary='Boleto')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Usuario('{self.username}')"

    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    tickets = db.relationship('Ticket', backref='owner')


class Event(db.Model):
    """
    Model for an event
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    # siglas = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    capacity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    place = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    picture = db.Column(db.String(100),
                        server_default="/uploads/default-event-image.png",
                        nullable=False, )

    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

    tickets = db.relationship('Ticket', backref='belongs_to')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Event('{self.name}')"


class Ticket(db.Model):
    """
    Ticket Model
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    event = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
    user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

And here is the error

```
$ flask migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 311, in _resolve_name
    rval = d[token]
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 729, in __missing__
    self[key] = val = self.creator(key)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 290, in _access_cls
    return self.fallback[key]
KeyError: 'Ticket'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1254, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1297, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 542, in get_command
    rv = info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 392, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from models import User, UserSchema
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/models.py", line 49, in <module>
    class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 124, in __new__
    dict_cls=dict_cls,
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 93, in get_declared_fields
    fields.update(mcs.get_declared_sqla_fields(fields, converter, opts, dict_cls))
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 139, in get_declared_sqla_fields
    dict_cls=dict_cls,
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 92, in fields_for_model
    for prop in model.__mapper__.iterate_properties:
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2082, in iterate_properties
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3280, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1967, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 197, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2076, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2138, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.entity.persist_selectable
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 883, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2043, in entity
    argument = self.argument()
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 315, in _resolve_name
    self._raise_for_name(name, err)
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 301, in _raise_for_name
    from_=err,
  File "/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class User->user, expression 'Ticket' failed to locate a name ('Ticket'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
(venv) eduardo@the-tardis:~/Escritorio/ldaw-api
```

Comment: You need to show the code in your `/home/eduardo/Escritorio/ldaw-api/models.py`. My guess is you'll need to import your `Event` and `Ticket` models into this file too.

Comment: @PGHE The above corresponds to models.py

Comment: I think you used rails code in this section: db.relationship('Ticket', backref='belongs_to'). Am I wrong or should it be backref = "ticket"?

Comment: @Detlef tbh I was just following this tutorial

Comment: From your error the line `class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):` is causing an error. You'll need to show more code.